# How do I made the header fixed without adding padding?

Tags: css

I want to make my header fixed. But my header is overlapping my body content. I know there is a way to fix it, adding padding. But for some pages, I have to add padding-top: 20px; and for another page I have to add padding-top 50px; 
Also, for responsive I have to keep change the padding-top. Anyone know how do it in dynamic way?

```
#top-header-wrapper {
 background-color: gray;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Nope...if you have different size headers for different pages, you'd either need JS to set the top padding or do it manually.

Comment: Not sure I understand you...is the header sitting on top of the rest of your content? Can you post more code or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a `header` element with the `position` value of `fixed`; as you've notice it will sit "on top" of the proceeding element.

Using the `padding-top` property is one way of making sure to ensure that your `header` doesn't 'block' content on the proceeding element (let's pretend it is a `section` element):

```
header ~ section {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Like you've said, one issue is that if the `header` does not have a static height (which it probably should) and when switching viewport sizes, you have to change the `padding-top` value.

Personally, I don't think that's so much of an issue, since [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) are easy to use.

With CSS, it is your only option, however. That are ways to use javascript to get an elements `height` and set the `padding-top` of another element to the first elements `height`, but since you are asking about css, your best bet is to use `@media` rules.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How about using jquery? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @sisi using jQuery makes it really simple - here is a [basic example using jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/9buk61nz/) - use [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) as to include `padding`, `border` and `margin` of the `header` element and just apply it to the proceeding element via [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)